# dispatchqueue in swift 3 appears as unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, swift3

I am trying to take/record video asynchronously on the main thread. However, when I call `dispatch.main.async`, I always get the error:

```
use of unresolved identifier DispatchQueue
```

I've looked everywhere from WWDC to Apple's Documentation, but I see no evidence of the type being deprecated.

Here is the code:

```
   if !self.cameraEngine.isRecording {
            if let url = CameraEngineFileManager.temporaryPath("video.mp4") {
                self.cameraButton.setTitle("stop recording", forState: [])
                self.cameraEngine.startRecordingVideo(url, blockCompletion: { (url: NSURL?, error: NSError?) -> (Void) in
                    if let url = url {

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.cameraButton.setTitle("start recording", for: .normal)
                            CameraEngineFileManager.saveVideo(url, blockCompletion: { (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> (Void) in
                                if success {
                                    let alertController =  UIAlertController(title: "Success, video saved !", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            self.cameraEngine.stopRecordingVideo()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can either put

```
import Foundation
```

or

```
import Dispatch
```

at the beginning of your code to start using **DispatchQueue class** without any issue.

Comment: import Dispatch did it for me. I was running my code in IBM Swift Sandbox by the way... Thanks!

Comment: `import Dispatch` works on Ubuntu

Comment: Seems like `Foundation` is deprecated on Swift 5 / XCode 11 Beta 5

Answer (score 4):

The giveaway here is this line:

```
self.cameraButton.setTitle("stop recording", forState: [])
```

That is *not Swift 3*. Therefore your file is a Swift 2.3 file. Therefore there is no such thing as DispatchQueue. You should be using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ...
```

Comment: The OP is probably better off rewriting their code to be Swift 3 compliant. There's probably no need to learn Swift 2.3 at this point, since it's largely obsolete and there's probably not much of a codebase that would require it.

Comment: And, in fact, matt's answer is a bit confusing/misleading, as it's presenting a Swift 2.3 solution. The better, more durable solution would be to convert the 2.3 code into 3.x code. There's no point in supporting a legacy version of Swift going forwards.. When I read matt's answer, I initially thought that I needed to learn this dispatch_async syntax, when, in fact, DispatchQueue was already a better and newer syntax..

Comment: @Gino dude you want me to rewrite whole legacy app when I can use 1 line of code? Thank f for Matt's answer!

Answer (score 1):

I do think that you don't have one of these in your frameworks list.
Try to import one of these and try putting DispatchQueue's in your file.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
// Any System Framework
```

This can happen if your file is not a Swift file, or your file is a Swift file but you don't have any frameworks on the top.

Comment: I have imported both SDKs in my project however the problem still persists