# Swift 3.0 unresolved identifier for DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I have been trying to find the answer to this for hours now but still no avail. I am trying to use the following code:

```
func fetchPosts() {
    ref.child("Amore").child("Posts").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let postMod = ReviewsPostModel()

            postMod.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
            self.posts.insert(postMod, atIndex: 0)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

In Swift 3.0.1, but it is saying that "DispatchQueue" is an unresolved identifier. I have imported Dispatch, and made sure that the class was pointed at the right target file. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will try right now. Thank you.

Comment: @matt have done this and still gives me an unresolved identifier error

Comment: Is the code you posted in your question your real, actual code, copy and pasted exactly as-is into your question? You may have a typo in your real code that doesn't appear in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679260/dispatchqueue-in-swift-3-appears-as-unresolved-identifier this thread seems to have a similar problem but there is not a solution here unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you *say* you are using Swift 3.0.1, you are not. You are using Swift 2.3. Thus, there is no such thing as DispatchQueue. Your code needs to be written like this:

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: And exactly the same thing is true of the other question that you linked to! What are the chances...?

Comment: For the most part, there's no point in trying to use Swift 2.3, as it's pretty much been obsoleted by Swift 3.x. The OP would be better off simply translating their 2.3 code to 3.x and NOT the other way around.. Personally, I found the above 2.3 answer misleading/confusing, as I initially read it to mean that I needed to change my code to move *away* from DispatchQueue, when, in actuality, the move should be *toward* DispatchQueue, since it's 3.x feature..

Answer (score 8):

Recently, a simple swift script I had written was yielding this error when I ran it under Linux. The same script had worked fine under macOS.

Out of curiosity, I added an 'import Dispatch' to the top of the script and it then ran fine on Linux.

Comment: My code was compiling fine inside Xcode. On Linux I also had to "import Dispatch"

Comment: This should be the correct answer for this post. Swift compiles differently on Linux and Mac. `import Dispatch` is the appropriate solution.